# Linq .net core 3.1 When called from 'VisitLambda', rewriting a node of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression' must return

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a problem with below exception:

> When called from 'VisitLambda', rewriting a node of type
> 'System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression' must return a non-null
> value of the same type. Alternatively, override 'VisitLambda' and
> change it to not visit children of this type.

it is related to this part of the code:

```cs
var teamEntries = _dataContext.TeamEntriesEntries
    .Where(c => TeamEntryIds.Contains(c.Id))
    .Include(c => c.TeamType);
    .Select(c => new
    {
        UserId = filteredCachedEntries.Any() ? filteredCachedEntries.Where (f => f.CurrentCalendarEntry != null && f.CurrentCalendarEntry.Id == c.Id).FirstOrDefault().UserId : 0,
        c.TeamType,
        Status = c.Progress != null ? c.Progress.Status : null,
    })
    .ToList();
```

Below line cause error (Where):

```cs
UserId = filteredCachedEntries.Any() ? filteredCachedEntries.Where (f => f.CurrentCalendarEntry != null && f.CurrentCalendarEntry.Id == c.Id).FirstOrDefault().UserId : 0
```

in .net core 2.2 everything was ok but right now it doesn't work and show me exceptaion.

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x? What is the type of `filteredCacheEntries`?

Comment: Is filteredCacheEntries an IQueryable? or a client side list?

Comment: @NetMage EF Core 3.x
filteredCacheEntries is a list

Comment: Yeah, then rework your query to `.Select(... db fields ...).AsEnumerable().Select( ... client evaluation ...)`

Answer (score 2):

Extract the data you need from the server and then do client side processing on the client side data:

```
var teamEntries = _dataContext.TeamEntriesEntries
    .Where(c => TeamEntryIds.Contains(c.Id))
    .Select(c => new {
        cID = c.Id,
        c.TeamType,
        Status = c.Progress.Status,
    })
    .AsEnumerable() // switch to client side processing
    .Select(c => new {
        UserId = filteredCachedEntries
            .Where(f => f.CurrentCalendarEntry.Id == c.cID)
            .Select(f => f.UserId)
            .FirstOrDefault(),
        c.TeamType,
        c.Status
    })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, query is wrong. EF Core 2.2 just evaluates everything on the client in that case. Removed everything that is not needed for correct SQL translation.

```cs
var teamEntries = _dataContext.TeamEntriesEntries
    .Where(c => TeamEntryIds.Contains(c.Id))
    .Select(c => new
    {
        UserId = filteredCachedEntries
            .Where(f => f.CurrentCalendarEntry.Id == c.Id)
            .Select(f => f.UserId)
            .FirstOrDefault(),
        c.TeamType,
        Status = c.Progress.Status,
    })
    .ToList();
```

Variant via LEFT JOIN

```cs
var teamEntries = 
    from c in _dataContext.TeamEntriesEntries
    where TeamEntryIds.Contains(c.Id)
    from f in filteredCachedEntries
       .Where(f => f.CurrentCalendarEntry.Id == c.Id)
       .Take(1)
       .DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {
        UserId = f.UserId,
        c.TeamType,
        Status = c.Progress.Status,
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: You forgot the `Include`.

Comment: I don't need, and EF Core translator also.

Comment: I don't follow. Also, missing the `f` in the `Select` for `.UserId`. Also, this would still be a bug in EF Core of whatever version to cause an exception in `VisitLambda`.

Comment: Yes, it is a bug in EF Core. But simple resolution when writing EF Core ready query.

Comment: there is still a bug related to VisitLambda

Comment: Post stack trace. It can be not EF Core bug but third-party extension.

Comment: in my opinion bug is here:
`filteredCachedEntries.Where(f => f.CurrentCalendarEntry != null && f.CurrentCalendarEntry.Id == c.Id)`

Comment: It is widely used OUTER APPLY. It should work. Post `filteredCachedEntries` code.

Comment: I get the same error testing your query with EF Core 3.1 on SQL server.

Comment: @Emil, added another variant. But I think `f.CurrentCalendarEntry.Id` should be replaced with `f.CurrentCalendarEntryId` if you have such field.